# Regex to find more than 2 adjoining characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I need to find if a given string contains more than 2 adjoining characters. For Example;

`Test123` - Should return true because it has 123(more than 2) adjoining numbers.

`TestABC` - Return true because of ABC.

`Test` - Return false.

If anybody know the answer then please share. If Regex is not the solution then please advise any other way, thanks.

Comment: You wont get around `(?:abc|bcd|cde...)`, if you insist on using regex. I know there's a dupe somewhere, just can't find it.

Comment: The answer is to not use Regex. Simple for loop should be easier

Comment: what do you mean when you use 'adjoining characters'? should it return true for `abč`?

Comment: @Chizh It should return false.

Comment: why? there's c but with just a small accent

Comment: @Chizh because C != č

Comment: but it's possible to have some encoding where letters are placed as follows `abčc`

Comment: Test has 4 adjoining chars, so why should it return false?  Unclear.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a job for regex but more for char converted to int. Since every char has an int value, you can keep track of the difference between the chars like so:

```
static bool isValid(string s)
{
    int oldValue = int.MinValue;
    int consecutiveCounter = 0;

    foreach (char item in s)
    {
        if(Math.Abs((int)item - oldValue) <= 1)
        {
            consecutiveCounter++;
            oldValue = (int)item;

            if (consecutiveCounter == 2)
                return true;
            else
                continue;
        }

        oldValue = (int)item;
        consecutiveCounter = 0;
    }

    return false;
}
```